# Long running task api call from logic app to avoid timeout bad request response after many retiries in .Net Core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, azure-logic-apps, asp.net-core-3.0, azure-api-apps

I  have an azure api app exposing some business apis.
I need to implement Long running task strategy because I want to call one of these apis from my Logic App because that api takes more than 2 minutes (which is the request **timeout limit**) to respond.

I have read the **[documentation of Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-create-api-app#webhook-actions)** and I also tried the **git sample** provided [here](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppTriggersExample/blob/master/LogicAppTriggers/Controllers/WebhookTriggerController.cs).
Unfortunately, that didn’t help me much because the samples on git are not very explicit and not compatible with `.Net Core 3.0.`

So, Actually, I am using asp net core 3.0. using DI and async calls in my app.
Here an example of a controller api that I want to test

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("PollDataIntoProduction")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PrePollData()
        {
            await _pollingService.ProduceData();
            return Ok($"Polling Execution Success at {DateTime.Now}");
        }
```

`_pollingService` is the service injected with DI that does the work for me and is async

And here is an http call example inside my logic app (which taking more than 2 minutes and causing bad request and timeout )

[image]

Can anyone provide me a working code sample with .Net Core 3.0 on how I can effectively implement `the webhook pattern` to wait for my api to finish processing in my logic app please?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: May I know what you want to do in this method "_pollingService.ProduceData()" ? And could you please share the git sample you mentioned in your question ?

Comment: this methods makes some business transformation after interacting with database via EF Core and

Comment: Hi Haithem, does the business transformation contains more than one operation ? And is it possible to use multi-threaded asynchronous calls to do the operations to save time ? If not, I suggest you to call the api app in azure function and [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-azure-functions#create-functions-inside-logic-apps) function inside the logic app.

Comment: yes it is asynchronous already and does multiple operations.
I cannot use azure functions because the call to an azure function because the webhook call to the azure function will as well get time out

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to approach this

1. **WebHook Pattern**
   For this you will have to use the [WebHook action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-webhook#add-an-http-webhook-action), which calls a subscription API triggering the asynchronous job in the background. This job would have to call the callback Url passed along with the subscribe API call.

   In your code, instead of `await`ing the `pollingService` method, you would call it directly by passing in the `callbackUrl` passed from the Logic App and later call that URL once ready.
2. **Async Pattern**
   For this you will have to use the [HTTP action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-native-http#add-an-http-action) with asynchronous pattern enabled in its settings. This would make the call to your service which returns a `202 Accepted` response with a status URL set in the `location` header, which the Logic App will poll until completion.

   If you are using Azure Functions, the [Durable Functions Async Pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview#async-http) is a perfect fit for this.

   In ASP.NET Core, apart from responding with a `202 Accepted` with the appropriate location header, you would have to implement a status endpoint which checks the progress of the background task.

   Also, if your service is scaled out to multiple instances, you would need to implement using external store, like Redis, for maintaining the status of such jobs.

Comment: can you please share a code sample, because this explanation exists in official documents of Microsoft; Many thanks

Comment: How did you finally implemented it?